# Развертывание веб приложения в Cloud 9

Tags: node.js, развертывание, heroku

Пытаюсь выполнить развертывание веб приложения по схеме [туториала](http://charless.org/?p=283). Но натыкаюсь на ошибку

> fatal: 'init' does not appear to be a git repository
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Попробовал сделать как описано на оф сайте heroku в [этом](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) разделе. Опять же та же
ошибка. После ввода команды

> $ git push heroku master

Подскажите как правильно сделать deploy приложения?

Comment: Я так понял нужно скопировать проект из Cloud 9 в github. Но как это сделать я не знаю